# Why is the CLASSPATH failing for Python but working for RazorSQL?

Tags: java, python, sql-server, jython, windows-server-2016

On Windows Server 2016, we are trying to connect over JDBC with a Jython script but it is giving following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

RazorSQL, on the same machine, connects without error using these settings:

```
Driver Class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
Driver Location: \Program Files (x86)\RazorSQL\drivers\sqlserver\sqljdbc.jar
```

As a result, we set the CLASSPATH to same location with this command:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\RazorSQL\drivers\sqlserver\sqljdbc.jar
```

...but when running the code below - we still get the same ClassNotFound error.

This is our Python code:

```
jclassname = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
database = "our_database_name"
db_elem = ";databaseName={}".format(database) if database else ""
host = "###.##.###.###" # ip address
port = "1433"     
user = "user_name"     
password = "password"   

url = (     jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port}{db_elem}"         ";user={user};password={password}".format( host=host, port=port, db_elem=db_elem,   er=user, password=password)     )     
print url        
driver_args = [url]    
jars = None   
libs = None  
db = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname, driver_args, jars=jars, libs=libs)
```

This is how we are running our Python script:

```
C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jython.exe C:\path_to_our_script.py
```

How is that RazorSQL is connecting fine - but somehow Python cannot? How do we remove this CLASSPATH error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the JARs at runtime using the system Classloader.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638390/6042824) answer.

The following code snippet has been taken from [this](https://gist.github.com/seansummers/073701193ef623d2bf55) Gist.

> ```
> def loadJar(jarFile):
>     '''load a jar at runtime using the system Classloader (needed for JDBC)
>
>     adapted from http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=300557
>     Author: Steve (SG) Langer Jan 2007 translated the above Java to Jython
>     Reference: https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/January2007/3
>     Author: seansummers@gmail.com simplified and updated for jython-2.5.3b3+
>
>     >>> loadJar('jtds-1.3.1.jar')
>     >>> from java import lang, sql
>     >>> lang.Class.forName('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver')
>     <type 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'>
>     >>> sql.DriverManager.getDriver('jdbc:jtds://server')
>     jTDS 1.3.1
>     '''
>     from java import io, net, lang
>     u = io.File(jarFile).toURL() if type(jarFile) <> net.URL else jarFile
>     m = net.URLClassLoader.getDeclaredMethod('addURL', [net.URL])
>     m.accessible = 1
>     m.invoke(lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), [u])
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     import doctest
>     doctest.testmod()
> ```

Also look at - https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/January2007/3

Comment: Brilliant - this appears to have gotten us past the error. Now on to a "1st arg can't be coerced to String" error with jaydebeapi.connect.