# Why doesn't jrunscript honor my classpath?

Tags: java, classloader, rhino, jdbc, jsr223

I'm trying to do some JDBC access from JavaScript using the Rhino included in Java 6. But I cannot make the `DriverManager` find the `Driver` I want to use.

These two examples should be equivalent:

Java:

```
public class DbTest {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        java.sql.Connection c = null;
        try {
            java.lang.Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            c = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver/mydb", "user", "password");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            c = null;
            System.out.println(e);
        };

        if(c != null) {
           System.out.println("yay, got c!");
           try {
               c.close();
           }
           catch(Exception e) {}
        } else {
           System.out.println("awww.");
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
importPackage(Packages.net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc);
java.lang.Class.forName('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver');
var c = null;
try {
    c = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
        'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver/mydb', 'user', 'password');
}
catch (e) {
    c = null;
    println(e);
};

if(c) {
   println('yay, got c!');
   c.close();
} else {
   println('awww.');
}
```

... but when I run them I get this behaviour:

Java:

```
> java -cp .;jtds-1.2.5.jar DbTest
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'myserver'.
awww.
```

That's great, it managed to load the driver and tried to resolve the server.

JavaScript:

```
> jrunscript -cp .;jtds-1.2.5.jar dbtest.js
script error in file dbtest.js :
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: 
Wrapped java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver (dbtest.js#2) in dbtest.js at line number 2
```

Why doesn't it find the class? I have tried with and without `importPackage()` and `importClass()`, with and without the `Packages` prefix. If I comment out `forName`, then `DriverManager` doesn't find a suitable driver.

Comment: Tried it in Linux now as well, exact same behaviour. Also tried running `java -cp blabla com.sun.tools.script.shell.Main dbtest.js`, no difference.

Comment: Suspecting that this is a security issue and that the scripting engine runs using its own classloader. So the question is where that can be modified.

Tried running an Ant `<script />`, which has a classpath attribute, obviously for the benefit of the script. Also does not work.

Comment: `java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar -Xbootclasspath:"$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/resources.jar:jtds-1.2.5.jar" com.sun.tools.script.shell.Main dbtest.js` works. But I want to know why neither `jrunscript` nor `<script />` seem to be using the normal classpath, and which one they _do_ use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [an IBM DeveloperWorks forum post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14486781), "*the jrunscript -classpath value is used by a separate "scripting" classloader that parallels the usual application classloader and that is used to resolve classes that have been mentioned in importClass() and importPackage()*".

And according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288828/how-to-use-a-jdbc-driver-from-an-arbitrary-location/289839#289839), "*... DriverManager performs "tasks using the immediate caller's class loader instance"* ".

So, unless you put the driver jar into the bootclasspath or find a way to modify how `jrunscript` (and Ant `<script />`) set the system classloader of the script environment, the only way to get this to work seems to be to skip `DriverManager` entirely:

```
var c = null;
try {
    var p = new java.util.Properties();
    p.setProperty('user', 'user');
    p.setProperty('password', 'password');
    c = (new net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver()).connect(
             'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver/mydb', p);
}
catch (e) {
    c = null;
    println(e);
};

if(c) {
   println('yay, got c!');
   c.close();
} else {
   println('awww.');
}
```

It removes one layer of indirection, which may or may not be ones cup of tea, but it works (with real server/user/passwd inserted):

```
$ jrunscript -cp jtds-1.2.5.jar dbtest_realparams.js 
yay, got c!
```